# Convert List<Map> to List<Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java

I have the following code block where I want to convert Map to `Map<String,Object>` . Is there a better a way to do what I am trying to achieve

```java
// users -> List<Map> 
List<Map<String, Object>> updatedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map user : users) {
user.put(enclosedListName, removeFromList(data, (List<Map<String, Object>>) user.get(enclosedListName)));
updatedUsers.add(user);   
}
someMethod(updatedUsers); //method expects List<Map<String,Object>>, how can i use users directly instead of updatedUsers
```

Comment: Depends on what you need as your key and what kinds of `Objects` are allowed. Please update with what you need exactly.

Comment: I already have a method for bulkInsert(List<Map<String,Object>>). I want to use the existing method

Comment: @madcolonel10 Not particularly. The *problem* here is that `users` is using a raw type. Fix the problem at the source. You should not have to rely on casting it.

Comment: @Michael i am getting users directly from mongodb find method, it returns in this format
public List<Map> findUsersByApplicationId(String applicationId) {
        Query q = new Query(Criteria.where
                (getEnclosedEntityListName() + ".itApplicationId").
                is(applicationId));

        return mongoTemplate.find(q, Map.class, getCollectionName());
    }

Comment: @madcolonel10 If you *know* that the results are `Map<String,Object>` then casting is ok.

Comment: What is the content of `List<Map>`? If it already holds maps where keys are strings then you could cast it directly to `List<Map<String, Object>>` but that also assumes that you don't want to modify its structure (like adding new maps, or changing map key-values pairs). Anyway it is unclear what you really want to do here and why which suggests it may be yet another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use streams (or you might not!).

However, the main problem is `Object`. In general, avoid losing static type information that you are going to need later.

We have `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Presumably each element of the `List` may have a differently parameterised `Map`s. Depending on what you want to do to the `Map` there are different options.

If you are just moving about elements within the map and some common method, you can use `Map<String, ? extends Common>` and capture that wildcard:

```
// Will accept Map<String, ?>
static <T> void swapAB(Map<String, T> map) {
    // Odd behaviour involving nulls for this code - ignore that.
    T a = map.get("A");
    T b = map.get("B");
    map.put("A", a);
    map.put("B", b);
}
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the `Map` within another object that contains all the methods needed by the client.

```
interface UpdatedUser {
    public void fn(Blah blah);
    public void gn(Donkey donkey);
}

public static UpdateUser barUpdateUser(Map<String, Bar> map) {
    return new UpdatedUser {

        public void fn(Blah blah) {
            // Can  happily operate on map values.
        };
        public void gn(Donkey donkey) {
        }
    };
}
```

If you want the actual values and there is a fixed set of possibilities, you can perform a kind of switch (a degenerate visitor).

```
interface UpdateUserSwitch {
    void bar(Map<String,Bar> bars);
    void foo(Map<String,Foo> foos);
}
```

In `UpdatedUser`:

```
void swtch(UpdateUserSwitch swtch);
```

In that anonymous inner class

```
public void swtch(UpdateUserSwitch swtch) {
    swtch(map);
}
```

(You can add a return type parameter in place of `void` if you wish.)